# How to graph multiple vertically offset density functions

Tags: r, time-series, density-plot

I have a time series of univariate distributions that I'd like to visualize more compactly. i know how to add multiple density functions to the same set of axes, but I'd like to vertically offset each function to get show the evolution of the distribution through time.

Comment: what would be your y-axis?

Comment: Show you current R-code, please.

Comment: i actually don't have any code yet. i have a monthly vectors of cell length data that range from 70-150 microns. it would be like stacking:

plot(density(x))

one on top of the other, but unlike the answer below, i'd like them offset vertically with a single x-axis at the bottom, and perhaps a single y-axis for one of the distributions. I simply need them more condensed than the stacked format below. any thoughts?

if you can access it, Fig. 9 from this publication is what i'm after:
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0022-3646.1997.00924.x/full

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot is great for this type of stuff (here just using the same distro):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=values, color=ind)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ ind, ncol=1)
```

[image]

And the toy data I used:

```
df <- stack(setNames(replicate(5, dnorm((-30:30)/10), s=F), letters[1:5]))
df$x <- ave(df$value, df$ind, FUN=seq_along)
```

Comment: OP seems to want these on the same set of axes